# I need to change the color and fill of a barplot

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart, fill

I have the following code that I used to create a barplot:

```
barplot(table(data$r_difficulty), ylab = "count", xlab = "r_difficulty")
```

I was wondering how I can change the fill and color with this code.

Comment: You will find this information in the help page for `barplot`. `?barplot`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `col=` argument for the fill color and `border=` for the border, among others it accepts numeric vectors  of predefined colors from 1 to 8 (see below).

```
barplot(table(dat$value), ylab = "count", xlab = "r_diff", col=1:8, border=8:1)
```

You may also:

- use a vector of color names such as `c("red", "blue")`, check `colors()` for all available color names
- define any RGB color such as `#FF0000`, or  `#FF000000` where the additional two digits are for the alpha (transparency)
- use color palettes such as the builtin `rainbow`, `hcl.colors`, `heat.colors` etc., or those of a whole bunch of additional packages
- mix some of the listed possibilities

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(value=sample(8, 100, replace=TRUE))
```